# How to access DLL in bin folder of ASP.NET MVC project?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to use the following to access a DLL in the project's bin folder:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult EncryptFile()
            {
                Assembly SampleAssembly;


                var dllFile = new FileInfo(@".\\bin\\encrypt.dll");
                 SampleAssembly = Assembly.LoadFile(dllFile.FullName);
    //...trimmed...
}
```

I also attempted `var dllFile = new FileInfo(@"\\bin\\encrypt.dll");` (note lack of `.` before the filepath), but it did not work either. In the debugger, the `FullName` returns `\\\\bin\\encrypt.dll`    in this second case.

What can I do to make it locate the file?

Thank you.

Comment: You can try `new FileInfo(Server.MapPath(@"~/bin/encrypt.dll"))`

Comment: Have you tried just `encrypt.dll` or mapping a path to `~\\bin\\encrypt.dll`?

Comment: Is this a .NET DLL? And why do you need to load the assembly on the fly like this?

Comment: @mason it is a Visual C++ DLL. I don't know any other way other than loading on the fly like this to encrypt a file a user uploads from the browser. Do you have any suggestion? My intention is to send it to send the file to the routine in the DLL that encrypts the file.

Comment: @heinzbeinz thanks that worked

Comment: @stephen.vakil no I did not, but the solutions here worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do

```
Assembly SampleAssembly = Assembly.LoadFile(Server.MapPath(@"~/bin/encrypt.dll"));
```